# How to show my home directory in the Finder side bar?

Tags: finder, monterey

This is how I configure the Finder preferences:

[image: Finder preferences]

As you can see, my home directory is checked in the favorites, and my Mac Harddisk is checked in the locations.

When I open Finder, the side bar looks like this:

[image: Actual Finder side bar]
<sub>Click for full size</sub>

What can I do to actually see my home and my hard disk in the side bar?

This is on Mac OS 12.6.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the reveal arrow or Show, depending on OS, when you hover over Favourites.

[image: new] [image: old]

Comment: This is nearly the solution. I don't have a "Show" there, even while hovering over the word _Favorites_. However, when the mouse is over the favorites, suddenly a small `>` sign appears, and when i click this, the favorites suddenly appear. The same magic also works with _Locations_.

Comment: Oh, it has a reveal arrow in newer OSes.

Comment: Ah, this is called _reveal arrow_. Please put this into your answer too.

Comment: i've added, simplified & now show both versions of how it looks, depending on your OS.